# Word for collection of religion's essential writings

Tags: single-word-requests, religion

I'm looking for a single word to describe the collection of all letters, scriptures and books specific to a religion, something like *teachings* but with a stronger emphasis on the written aspect.

Comment: _Scripture_ or _scriptures_ don't fit the situation already?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might consider using *canon*: Theravada canon, Mahayana canon.

Comment: Can't deny you've found *the* single word there, bro!

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for, thanks !

Comment: If I'd just been asked to say what *canon* means in a religious context, think I'd have said some kind of priest, or the special laws and rules of churches. I do know this precise meaning (I think I *did*), but it wouldn't come to mind easily.

Comment: Canon also applies to non-religous aswell. The 'Sherlock Holmes canon' would be all the s.h. stories

Answer (score 3):

They're usually just called the **Sacred texts**, but I guess you know that. Still, given that they *are* called that, most likely anything else suggested won't actually be what people usually call them.

Having said that, Jasper Loy's **canon** *can* be used quite specifically in this sense (along with a *lot* of other senses). But not everyone would understand it, I suggest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I will probably end up using _sacred texts_ sooner or later to diversify a bit.

Comment: @Parusa: If you're going to write it so often you're thinking of ringing the changes, I guess it's going to be a context where there's no risk of *canon* not being understood. With any luck you might get some more alternatives here - variety is the spice of life!